# Add Charsetprovider to the OJVM

Tags: java, database, oracle, jvm

I need to add a new charsetprovider to my OJVM inside my Oracle 12c database.

I load my class with loadjava :

```
  loadjava -v -u user MyNewCharsetProviderClass.jar
```

My Class go in my oracle schema, all the direct method work. But the CharsetProvider part do not load with the serviceloader.

In pure java I add it in meta-inf/services and the serviceloader load it but in oracle database java VM it seem to not work this way. My CharsetProvider class simply not load. My class work fine in pure java, I use it from many years ago.

META-INF/services : java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider content :

```
com.eric.newcharset.nio.charset.spi.newcharsetCharsetProvider
```

Code example inside the database :

```
create or replace and compile java source named "MyJavaDbProcedure" as

public class MyJavaDbProcedure {
   public static String upcase(String text) {
     String str;
        try {
            str = new String("ééeeaarrr".getBytes("windows-1252"), "NEWCHARSET");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex.toString();
        }
    return str;
   }
 };
```

when I call it, t I have always a java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException : newcharset.

Comment: I doubt there is a solution. Try `Class.forName("com.eric.newcharset.nio.charset.spi.newcharsetCharsetProvider");`.

Comment: Good try but no... but it's confirm to me the class as been loaded (because I don't have any "not found error") but the class java.nio.io.charset.spi.AnselCharsetProvider as not been extended...

Comment: Then there is [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) but maybe better look into the sources of Charset.

Comment: Thank's it what I'm doing right now... re-inventing the wheel !